# Accessing class members defined in another *.cs file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm writing an update checker for my program and I'm using xml from a remote server. The request is working fine and it does what I want. The problem is that I can't call the function from another file. (See code below)

**The files**

- home.cs - The place i want to call the `RequestVersion()`
- version.cs - Where the `RequestVersion()` is located

**The code**

***version.cs***

```
namespace MyName
{
class version
{
    public string[] RequestVersion()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string[] version_data = new string[3];
            doc.Load("link_here");
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                string version = node.Attributes[0].Value;
                string date = node["date"].InnerText;
                string changelog = node["changelog"].InnerText;

                version_data[0] = version;
                version_data[1] = date;
                version_data[2] = changelog;

                return version_data;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception xml_ex)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

(returns an array)

***home.cs***

```
 private void checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //This is the place from where i want to access the array!       
 }
```

And my XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SerialMate>
  <release version="1.0.0">
    <date>12-10-2014</date>
    <changelog>Test</changelog>
  </release>
</SerialMate>
```

(I'm not adding any new `<release>` tags on the xml so it always has 1)

**The question**

So, my question is: How do it access the array elements from the `RequestVersion()` within `home.cs`?

Comment: Is these two files are in the same project?

Comment: Please note that you should [never catch exceptions that you don't plan to do anything about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673860/what-does-only-catch-exceptions-you-can-handle-really-mean)

Comment: Consider changing the title,  please read this link to know more http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Unfortunately you're not giving us enough information to answer the question. We need to know what you are trying to put in `checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem_Click` and how the files are arranged in your solution (are they both in the same project? are they in the same namespace? Is the project currently compiling?) The xml, and `RequestVersion` implementation details are not relevant to this question. Likely Visual Studio is also not relevant.

Comment: If you write out the function call (just like robot suggests below) it would also be useful to know what build error you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem, but:

```
version v = new version();
string[] s = v.RequestVersion();
```

Comment: Also make sure you import the required namespance (MyName)

Answer (score 0):

**Referencing code within other files and projects**

Within the same project it makes absolutely no difference whether the code is in the same or in different files. The only things which matter are the access modifiers (`public`, `protected`, `internal`, and `private`).

If the two code pieces are in different projects, then the compiled code will be compiled into two different assemblies (`*.exe` or `*.dll`). Therefore one project will have to reference the other one. Typically the start up project (`*.exe`) will reference a class library project (`*.dll`).

If the two projects are within the same solution, you can add a so called project reference. Right click on the class library project in the solution explorer and click *“Copy As Project Reference”*. In the startup project, right click on *“References”* and click *“Paste Reference”*.

If the two projects are within different solutions you will have to add a reference to the class library DLL (usually the one in *bin/Release*) from within the startup project. Right click *“References”* and click *“Add Reference…”*. In the references dialog choose *“Browse”* and select the DLL.

Also make sure not to create circular dependencies (project A references project B and project B references project A). If you have such a dependency, you can usually resolve it by placing the code that has to be accessed by the two projects into a third project C. Then change the references to: A references C and B references C.

---

**Calling the method of another class**

Types (a class in your case) and their members (properties, methods, events …) must be declared as `public` in order to be accessible from other projects. Within the same project they can also be declared as `internal`. (They can also be declared as `protected` if you want to derive new classes.)

If a member is declared as `static` or if it is a constant, you can access it by specifying the type name dot the member name:

```
var result = MyClass.MyMethod();
```

If the member is an instance member you must call it from an instance of the type (an object):

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
var result = Obj.MyMethod();
```