# Catch all exceptions WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, logging

In my `App.xaml.cs`, I have these codes to catch the exceptions and log them

```
public App()
{
     SetupExceptionHandlingInApp();
     // other codes
}

private void SetupExceptionHandlingInApp()
{
     this.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) =>
     {
        e.Handled = true;
        //LOGGING CODE HERE
        this.Shutdown(-1);
     };
}

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
   SetupExceptionHandlingInMain();
   //other codes
}

private static void SetupExceptionHandlingInMain()
{   
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
    {
        //LOGGING CODE HERE                 
        Environment.Exit(1);
    };           

    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += (s, e) =>
    {
        //LOGGING CODE HERE
        Environment.Exit(1);
    };

    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
    {
        //LOGGING CODE HERE
    };
}
```

Almost cases, I can catch the exception and log it. But the application crashes sometimes while execution, and I can't find an error logged about the exception that caused the crash.

Am I missing a method besides the methods above to catch the exception? I looked at some article on SO but almost them used these methods above.

The log4net works well because I can see all ERROR and INFO log.

**EDIT**

After following the suggestion of Panagiotis Kanavos, I found out the error:

Application : xxx.exe

Version du Framework : v4.0.30319

Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une erreur interne dans le runtime .NET à l'adresse IP 547541C4 (54380000) avec le code de sortie 80131506.

**TRANSLATE**

Application: xxx.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

> Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in
>   the .NET Runtime at IP 547541C4 (54380000) with exit code 80131506.

Comment: How and from where does it crash?

Comment: @mm8 : the application crashes somewhere while execution because there is en exception non caught, the codes in the question is used to catch the exception. It works well but sometimes, there is an exception that they can't catch. That means

Comment: @ThierryV in case of an unhandled exception an application crash error is written in the Event log. Did you check the Event Viewer?

Comment: Why do you think that `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` is at all useful for a **WPF** application? There's a reason why that exists in the WinForms DLL and not in WPF's

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto with the hope that I don't miss any exception, I tried to use it but I can't catch the exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank for suggesting, I updated the post, I'm searching how to fix the exception

Comment: @ThierryV which .NET runtime version are you using? Perhaps the problem can be solved simply by updating to a newer runtime. That's the only thing you can do if the problem is caused by a .NET bug anyway

Comment: As a side note: it is not recommended to just catch all exceptions, rather you should only catch exceptions that you can handle. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673895/2471080 . Other exceptions will be catched by the CLR, so it can create a log and a mem-dump. Maybe you can also load this mem-dump into Visual Studio to get more info about the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Is this happening inside of an asynchronous method?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you got an exception that corrupted the state of the process? From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, this event is not raised for
>   exceptions that corrupt the state of the process, such as stack
>   overflows or access violations, unless the event handler is
>   security-critical and has the
>   [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute.

Perhaps you can temporarily specify that your handler is security-critical to be able to catch the exception during debugging.